# MYSQL query data is not displaying on line chart in dashboard

Tags: mysql, node-red, linechart

I am fairly new to JS and node red. I have data from sensors that is stored in a MYSQL database.
I display a user query from the database on my dashboard and it all works when called
I now want to display the different fields (batt,temp,light etc) on a line chart with a time base as x.

The graph shows up on my dashboard with the y axis formatted to scale, but no lines or data. here is the flow.

```
[
    {
        "id": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "show stud data",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "80a060da.8c1db",
        "type": "ui_template",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "group": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "name": "From Database",
        "order": 7,
        "width": "17",
        "height": "7",
        "format": "<style>\ntable\n{\n    background:black;\n}\n.main\n{\n\n\n    height:1500px;\n}\n</style>\n<div class=\"main\">\n<table style=\"width:100%\">\n  <tr>\n    <th>Date</th> \n    <th>Time</th>\n    <th>Stud</th>\n    <th>Batt</th>\n    <th>Charge</th>\n    <th>Signal</th>\n    <th>Temperature</th>\n    <th>Light</th>\n\n  \n  </tr>\n  <tr ng-repeat=\"x in msg.payload | limitTo:10000\">\n    <td>{{msg.payload[$index].datum}}</td>\n    <td>{{msg.payload[$index].timing}}</td>\n    <td>{{msg.payload[$index].position}}</td>\n    <td>{{msg.payload[$index].battery}}</td>\n    <td>{{msg.payload[$index].charge}}</td>\n    <td>{{msg.payload[$index].signalstrength}}</td>\n    <td>{{msg.payload[$index].temperature}}</td>\n    <td>{{msg.payload[$index].light}}</td>\n   \n\n  </tr>\n</table>\n</div>",
        "storeOutMessages": true,
        "fwdInMessages": true,
        "resendOnRefresh": false,
        "templateScope": "local",
        "className": "",
        "x": 960,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2134256f.8304f2",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "name": "",
        "func": "var data = context.get('data') || { value: \"\", condition: \">=\" };\nvar topic = msg.topic;\nvar payload = msg.payload;\nif (topic == \"position\")\n    data.site = msg.payload;\nif (topic == \"value\")\n    data.value = msg.payload;\nif (topic == \"condition\")\n    data.condition = msg.payload;\nif (topic == \"sdatum\")\n    data.sdate = msg.payload;\nif (topic == \"edatum\")\n    data.edate = msg.payload;\n\nvar d = new Date();\nvar now = d.getDate();\nif (data.edate == undefined || data.edate == \"\")\n    edate = now;\nelse\n    var edate = data.edate;\n\nif (data.sdate == undefined || data.sdate == \"\")\n    var sdate = now;\nelse\n    sdate = data.sdate;\ncontext.set('data', data)\nif (sdate == 0) {\n    var part_msg = \"\";\n\n}\nelse {\n    var part_msg = \" AND TIMESTAMP >\" + sdate + \" AND TIMESTAMP<\" + edate + \" \";\n}\nif (topic == \"submit\") {\n    var query = \"\";\n    if (data.value == undefined || data.value == \"\") {\n        if (data.site != undefined)\n            query = \"SELECT * FROM studs.stud_status WHERE position=\" + \"\\\"\" + data.site + \"\\\"\" + \"AND timestamp_ >= \" + sdate + \"\";//\" + \"\\\"\" + data.site + \"\\\" ORDER BY datum DESC\";\n    }\n    else if (data.value != undefined && data.value != \"\") {\n        if (data.site != undefined && data.condition != undefined) {\n            query = \"SELECT * FROM studs.stud_status WHERE position=\" + \"\\\"\" + data.site + \"\\\"\" + \" AND light \";\n            query = query + data.condition + data.value;\n            query = query + \" ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 100\";\n        }\n    }\n    node.log(\"query \" + query);\n    msg.topic = query;\n\n    context.set('data', data)\n    if (query = \"1\")\n        return msg;\n}\nreturn;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 420,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": [
            [
                "2ef4c453f4827be8",
                "9ade5738986f044c"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "b82db343.9fb4d",
        "type": "ui_dropdown",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "d": true,
        "name": "Query Type",
        "label": "Query Type",
        "tooltip": "",
        "place": "Select option",
        "group": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "order": 1,
        "width": "4",
        "height": "2",
        "passthru": false,
        "multiple": false,
        "options": [
            {
                "label": ">=",
                "value": ">=",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "<=",
                "value": "<=",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "=",
                "value": "=",
                "type": "str"
            }
        ],
        "payload": "",
        "topic": "condition",
        "topicType": "str",
        "className": "",
        "x": 130,
        "y": 220,
        "wires": [
            [
                "2134256f.8304f2"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "280eff25.001f5",
        "type": "ui_text_input",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "name": "value",
        "label": "value",
        "tooltip": "",
        "group": "f7a06e3b.8c35b",
        "order": 2,
        "width": "4",
        "height": "1",
        "passthru": false,
        "mode": "text",
        "delay": "100",
        "topic": "value",
        "sendOnBlur": true,
        "className": "",
        "topicType": "str",
        "x": 130,
        "y": 280,
        "wires": [
            [
                "2134256f.8304f2"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a372c41d.5e6968",
        "type": "ui_button",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "name": "submit",
        "group": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "order": 8,
        "width": "4",
        "height": "1",
        "passthru": false,
        "label": "Submit",
        "tooltip": "",
        "color": "",
        "bgcolor": "",
        "className": "",
        "icon": "",
        "payload": "1",
        "payloadType": "str",
        "topic": "submit",
        "topicType": "str",
        "x": 130,
        "y": 360,
        "wires": [
            [
                "2134256f.8304f2"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "6240d8.feb99f28",
        "type": "ui_date_picker",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "name": "start date",
        "label": "Start date",
        "group": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "order": 3,
        "width": "5",
        "height": "2",
        "passthru": true,
        "topic": "sdatum",
        "topicType": "str",
        "className": "",
        "x": 140,
        "y": 420,
        "wires": [
            [
                "2134256f.8304f2"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "8ab8621.bcbbca",
        "type": "ui_date_picker",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "d": true,
        "name": "End Date",
        "label": "End Date",
        "group": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "order": 4,
        "width": "4",
        "height": "4",
        "passthru": true,
        "topic": "edatum",
        "topicType": "str",
        "className": "",
        "x": 140,
        "y": 480,
        "wires": [
            [
                "2134256f.8304f2"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "159524314a5fae1a",
        "type": "ui_dropdown",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "name": "Stud Number",
        "label": "Stud Number",
        "tooltip": "Select the stud number to lookup",
        "place": "Select option",
        "group": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "order": 2,
        "width": "5",
        "height": "2",
        "passthru": false,
        "multiple": false,
        "options": [
            {
                "label": "1",
                "value": "1",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "2",
                "value": "2",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "3",
                "value": "3",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "4",
                "value": "4",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "5",
                "value": "5",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "6",
                "value": "6",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "7",
                "value": "7",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "8",
                "value": "8",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "9",
                "value": "9",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "10",
                "value": "10",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "11",
                "value": "11",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "12",
                "value": "12",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "13",
                "value": "13",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "14",
                "value": "14",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "15",
                "value": "15",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "16",
                "value": "16",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "17",
                "value": "17",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "18",
                "value": "18",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "19",
                "value": "19",
                "type": "str"
            },
            {
                "label": "20",
                "value": "20",
                "type": "str"
            }
        ],
        "payload": "",
        "topic": "position",
        "topicType": "str",
        "className": "",
        "x": 130,
        "y": 160,
        "wires": [
            [
                "2134256f.8304f2"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2ef4c453f4827be8",
        "type": "mysql",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "mydb": "6e9d84d500e8a508",
        "name": "stud status mysql",
        "x": 650,
        "y": 240,
        "wires": [
            [
                "80a060da.8c1db",
                "4c98e94c06312a2e"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "9ade5738986f044c",
        "type": "ui_text",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "group": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "order": 9,
        "width": "5",
        "height": "4",
        "name": "",
        "label": "Query sent",
        "format": "{{msg.topic}}",
        "layout": "col-center",
        "className": "",
        "x": 610,
        "y": 180,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "4c98e94c06312a2e",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "name": "charge graph",
        "func": "//var series = [\"Charge\"];\n//var labels = [\"Charge Values\"];\n//var data = msg.payload;\n//var thetime = Date.now()\n\nvar d = [\"[\"]\nfor (var i = 0; i < msg.payload.length; i++) {\n    d += '{ \"x\":' + msg.payload[i].timestamp_ + ', \"y\":' + msg.payload[i].battery + '}';\n    if (i < (msg.payload.length - 1)) {\n        d += \",\"\n    } else {\n        d += \"]\"\n    }\n}\n//var a = JSON.parse(d)\n\n\nvar f = [\"[\"]\nfor (var j = 0; j < msg.payload.length; j++) {\n    f += '{ \"x\":' + msg.payload[j].timestamp_ + ', \"y\":' + msg.payload[j].charge + '}';\n    if (j < (msg.payload.length - 1)) {\n        f += \",\"\n    } else {\n        f += \"]\"\n    }\n}\n//var b = JSON.parse(f)\n\nvar x = [\"[\"]\nfor (var m = 0; m < msg.payload.length; m++) {\n    x += '{ \"x\":' + msg.payload[m].timestamp_ + ', \"y\":' + msg.payload[m].temperature + '}';\n    if (m < (msg.payload.length - 1)) {\n        x += \",\"\n    } else {\n        x += \"]\"\n    }\n}\n//var c = JSON.parse(x)\n\nvar e = [\"[\"]\nfor (var m = 0; m < msg.payload.length; m++) {\n    x += '{ \"x\":' + msg.payload[m].timestamp_ + ', \"y\":' + msg.payload[m].light + '}';\n    if (m < (msg.payload.length - 1)) {\n        x += \",\"\n    } else {\n        x += \"]\"\n    }\n}\n//var c = JSON.parse(e)\n\nmsg.payload = [{\n    \"series\": [\"Battery\", \"Charge\", \"Temperature\", \"Light\"],\n    \"data\": [d, f, x, e],\n    \"labels\": [\"Battery\", \"Charge\", \"Temperature\", \"Light\"]\n}]\n\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 900,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "06b5672e66242ca5",
                "893a2823bb2e8272"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "893a2823bb2e8272",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "name": "debug 6",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "false",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 1120,
        "y": 420,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "06b5672e66242ca5",
        "type": "ui_chart",
        "z": "4447f1fa.c7a27",
        "name": "sql response",
        "group": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "order": 10,
        "width": "9",
        "height": "4",
        "label": "Line Chart",
        "chartType": "line",
        "legend": "true",
        "xformat": "auto",
        "interpolate": "linear",
        "nodata": "",
        "dot": false,
        "ymin": "",
        "ymax": "",
        "removeOlder": 1,
        "removeOlderPoints": "",
        "removeOlderUnit": "60",
        "cutout": 0,
        "useOneColor": false,
        "useUTC": false,
        "colors": [
            "#1f77b4",
            "#aec7e8",
            "#ff7f0e",
            "#2ca02c",
            "#98df8a",
            "#d62728",
            "#ff9896",
            "#9467bd",
            "#c5b0d5"
        ],
        "outputs": 1,
        "useDifferentColor": false,
        "className": "",
        "x": 1140,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "fe5b5e1b0beaa2ad",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "name": "Stud Reporting",
        "tab": "e9bbb610152bc753",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "35",
        "collapse": true,
        "className": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "f7a06e3b.8c35b",
        "type": "ui_group",
        "name": "Default",
        "tab": "ff84105b.764c3",
        "order": 1,
        "disp": true,
        "width": "12",
        "collapse": false
    },
    {
        "id": "6e9d84d500e8a508",
        "type": "MySQLdatabase",
        "name": "",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": "3306",
        "db": "studs",
        "tz": "",
        "charset": "UTF8"
    },
    {
        "id": "e9bbb610152bc753",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "name": "Test Stud Site Monitor",
        "icon": "dashboard",
        "order": 1,
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false
    },
    {
        "id": "ff84105b.764c3",
        "type": "ui_tab",
        "name": "SITE-RESULTS",
        "icon": "dashboard"
    }
]
```

My debug shows the output of the function, but I am still missing something.

```
[{"series":["Battery","Charge","Temperature","Light"],"data":["[{ \"x\":1666224007685, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224025963, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224034888, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224052898, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224069144, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224078075, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224095352, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224113105, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224122325, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224148086, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224157504, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224175330, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224192390, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224210452, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224219662, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224236774, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224254526, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224272308, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224281331, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224299058, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224316692, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224325516, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224343485, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224361261, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224370341, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224388056, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224405968, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224414740, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224432537, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224450218, \"y\":0.00},{ \"x\":1666224468251, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1666224477291, \"y\":0.01},{ \"x\":1...","[{ \"x\":1666224007685, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224025963, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224034888, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224052898, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224069144, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224078075, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224095352, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224113105, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224122325, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224148086, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224157504, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224175330, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224192390, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224210452, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224219662, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224236774, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224254526, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224272308, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224281331, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224299058, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224316692, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224325516, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224343485, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224361261, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224370341, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224388056, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224405968, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224414740, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224432537, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224450218, \"y\":412},{ \"x\":1666224468251, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224477291, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":1666224495556, \"y\":415},{ \"x\":166...","[{ \"x\":1666224007685, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224025963, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224034888, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224052898, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224069144, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224078075, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224095352, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224113105, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224122325, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224148086, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224157504, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224175330, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224192390, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224210452, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224219662, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224236774, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224254526, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224272308, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224281331, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224299058, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224316692, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224325516, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224343485, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224361261, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224370341, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224388056, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224405968, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224414740, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224432537, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224450218, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224468251, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1666224477291, \"y\":40.0},{ \"x\":1...",["["]],"labels":["Battery","Charge","Temperature","Light"]}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your data values are escaped JSON strings rather than objects. Without loading the flow to see how you are creating them, I would guess you need to either add or remove a JSON node (this will parse/stringify based on input) some where.

Comment: Here is my data array from the node. It now displays series and label but seems to plot all the data on the first timestamp.
data: array[4]
0: array[3733]
[0 … 9]
0: object
x: "1666223990314"
y: "0.00"
1: object
2: object
3: object
4: object
5: object
6: object
7: object
8: object
9: object
[10 … 19]